# Two try catch blocks on controller level

Tags: java, exception, jersey, try-catch, throw

I have a case in which I need duplicate try..catch block on controller level.
Let me provide sample code for this issue:

```
List<String> loadedList =
engine.findSomething(param); //At this point we can obtain Exception, so this code block we should move to existing try block or create another.. but the problem if we move this to try block below, the WebApplicationException that throws in condition below will be catched in existing try block..

// if not found - return NOT_FOUND.
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(loadedList)) {
    log.info(errorMessage);
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).type("text/plain").build()); //exception from Jersey lib
}

try {
    for (String item : loadedList) {
        //some business logic
        //I know that on controller layer we should avoid business logic but it is not my code and I can not change it..
    }
    return Response.ok().build();

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw processException(e); //Helper method that avoids code duplication when preparing webException
}
```

How can I refactor this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Spring controller?

Comment: "but it is not my code and I can not change it.." But you want to refactor it?

Comment: Yes, it is Spring controller, I can not move business logic because it is not in the scope of current task :)

Comment: You can catch the exception, check if it is an WebApplicationException and if it is then throw it again.

Answer (score 3):

You can benefit from @ControllerAdvice and implement global controller exception handler.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
    //handle error here
    return "error";
}
```

In order GlobalExceptionHandler to work, Exception must be thrown out of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a specific `try/catch` statement for the

```
List<String> loadedList = engine.findSomething(param);
```

invocation.

You should just declare `List<String> loadedList` before the call to `engine.findSomething(param);` in order that it is outside the `try catch` scope to be able to use it later.

```
List<String> loadedList = null;
try{
   loadedList = engine.findSomething(param); 
}
catch (Exception e){ // or a more specific exception if it makes sense
    // exception logging and processing    
}
```

Comment: But is it a good practise to use two try .. catch blocks in controller?

Comment: Doing it in a controller or somewhere else is not really a problem in itself. If you need to catch the exception to go on a processing, you have to catch the exception. If it is not the case, you have to let it to be propagated higher.

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
{
    List<String> loadedList = engine.findSomething(param); 

    // if not found - return NOT_FOUND.
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(loadedList)) {
       log.info(errorMessage);
       throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).type("text/plain").build()); //exception from Jersey lib
    }

    for (String item : loadedList) {
        //some business logic
        //I know that on controller layer we should avoid business logic but it is not my code and I can not change it..
    }
    return Response.ok().build();

}
//You can first catch WebApplicationException before the Exception and 
//redirect the throw to the parent class
catch(WebApplicationException we) 
{
    throw we;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw processException(e);
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this approach but unfortunatelly I am not sure if engine.findSomething(param) can throw WebApplicationException in another case..

Comment: @badCoder then create your own exception and make the "if" throw that exception instead WebApplicationException

Answer (score 1):

Another approach different from davidxxx one.

Move the code inside the `try..catch` clause. If it happens to throw the `WebApplicationException` then catch it, do whatever you need to do with it and then throw it again.

```
try {

List<String> loadedList =
engine.findSomething(param); 

// if not found - return NOT_FOUND.
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(loadedList)) {
    log.info(errorMessage);
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errorMessage).type("text/plain").build()); //exception from Jersey lib
}

    for (String item : loadedList) {
        //some business logic
        //I know that on controller layer we should avoid business logic but it is not my code and I can not change it..
    }
    return Response.ok().build();

} catch (WebApplicationException e1){
  //log the exception
  //throw it again using throw e1
} catch (Exception e2) {
    throw processException(e2); //Helper method that avoids code duplication when preparing webException
}
```